# ActiveMQ Classic JDBC Master Slave persistent issue with JDBC unable to lock the MySQL DB using MySQL 8 connector

Tags: mysql, jdbc, activemq-classic

When using just JDBC as the data source you can use a master-slave approach running two brokers (i.e. one for the master and another for the slave). I'm using the MySQL 8 connector for MySQL 5.7 and 8 clients. Below is the ActiveMQ configuration file:

```xml
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

     <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">

      <persistenceAdapter>
                <!-- <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/> -->
                 <jdbcPersistenceAdapter dataDirectory="activemq.data" dataSource="#mysql-ds"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>
    </broker>


    <bean id="mysql-ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.xx.x.xx:3306/activemq_veeru?serverTimezone=UTC"/>
        <property name="username" value="admin"/>
        <property name="password" value="admin"/>
        <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
    </bean>
```

While starting the service when below error that unable to lock the DB.

```
Using Persistence Adapter: JDBCPersistenceAdapter(org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource@6bd16207) | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
Starting Persistence Adapter: JDBCPersistenceAdapter(org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource@6bd16207) | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
Database adapter driver override not found for : [mysql_connector_j].  Will use default implementation. | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter | main
Database lock driver override not found for : [mysql_connector_j].  Will use default implementation. | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter | main
```

With `mysql-connector-java-5.1.49` and `activemq-jdbc-store-5.13.2` it's working without any issues. However, when I am upgrading the connector and jdbc store to `mysql-connector-j-8.0.31` and `activemq-jdbc-store-5.17.1` respectively I started this issue.

Comment: JIRA added: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-9397.  We'll try to get it in ActiveMQ 6.1.0 and the next 5.18.x

Answer (score 1):

ActiveMQ Classic takes the value from [`java.sql.DatabaseMetaData#getDriverName`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getDriverName()) provided by the JDBC driver and maps that to the name of a service file to find the right persistence adapter implementation. For example, if you were using [`mysql-connector-java-5.1.49.jar`](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.49/) the value from `getDriverName()` would be `MySQL Connector Java` which would map to the service file [`mysql_connector_java`](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/main/activemq-jdbc-store/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org/apache/activemq/store/jdbc/mysql_connector_java) which points to `org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.adapter.MySqlJDBCAdapter`.

However, since you're using `mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar` the value from `getDriverName()` is `MySQL Connector/J` which doesn't map to any service file in ActiveMQ Classic. In other words, it's not currently supported.

There is no version of ActiveMQ Classic which directly supports the MySQL 8 Connector/J. The latest MySQL JDBC driver you can use without falling back to the default adapter & lock driver is [6.0.6](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/6.0.6/).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, Tired the remaining the jar. No luck still facing the same issues unable to lock the db   Database adapter driver override not found for : [mysql_connector_j].  Will use default implementation. | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter

Comment: Thanks for following up. After some additional investigation I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks  I want to go with latest MySQL 8 J connector which is recommended for MySQL 8 client. So is there any version update for ActiveMQ which supports the MySQL 8 J connector for HA

Comment: There is no version of ActiveMQ "Classic" which directly supports the MySQL 8 Connector/J. As noted, the latest MySQL JDBC driver you can use without falling back to the default adapter & lock driver is 6.0.6.